# How can I remove a dot sourced script in PowerShell?

Tags: .net, powershell

If I have dot sourced :

```
. "\foo-bar.ps1"
```

How can I see obtain the list of all dot sourced scripts and how can I remove "foo-bar/ps1" from the dot sourced scripts?

Comment: basically it is like undrinking alcohol:  you can only mitigate the outcome, but not undrink completely.  in order to undrink one shouldn't drink or in PowerShell case, just put `#` as a first symbol in the line where you dot source

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't remove a dot sourced script. That is why modules where introduced in PowerShell 2.0. See [About_Modules](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847804.aspx)

You can convert your "foo-bar.ps1" to a module. A module can be imported (Import-Module) and removed (Remove-Module).

Answer (score 6):

You can remove sourced functions if you know the path of the dot-sourced file:

```
Get-ChildItem function: | 
Where-Object {$_.ScriptBlock.File -eq $path} | 
Remove-Item
```

Comment: Not sure how different things are from PS v5, but I can use `Remove-Item Function:\Get-WMIReboot` where `Get-WMIReboot` is the name of my function to be removed.  Confirm the function is gone using `dir function:`

Answer (score 5):

I agree with @JPBlanc that you cannot remove a dot-sourced script *in general* but depending on your own coding conventions you may be able to do this *in practice*.

First a couple observations about **why you cannot do this in general**:

(1) PowerShell has no notion of a dot-sourced script as a separate entity. Once you dot-source it, its contents becomes part of your current context, just as if you had manually typed each line at the prompt. Thus you cannot remove it because it does not actually exist:-)

(2) For the very same reason as (1) you cannot list dot-sourced scripts.

**Now, how to do it anyway:**

Depending on the contents and conventions of your dot-sourced script, though, you may be able to do what you want. If, for example, the script simply defines three functions--call these `func-a`, `func-b`, and `func-c`--then you *can* both **list** and **remove** those functions.

**List** assimilated functions:

```
Get-ChildItem function:func-*
```

**Remove** assimilated functions:

```
Remove-Item function:func-*
```